# drag and drop textview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have to drag and i am not able to drag it perfectly:
The issues are:
1) I have to drag two to three times to bring that to desired position.Hence textview is not following the finger movement smoothly.
2)If i move textview in upward direction its only going downwards.

I am providing the code of textview on touch event.Please help.Thanks in advance.

```
 final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
           t.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                float x = me.getX();
                float y = me.getY();

                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    status = START_DRAGGING;
                }
                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    status = STOP_DRAGGING;
                    t.setPadding((int) me.getX(), (int) me.getY(), 10, 10);

                    Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
                }  if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
                        System.out.println("Dragging");

                        t.setPadding((int) me.getX(), (int) me.getY(), 10, 10);

                        t.invalidate();
                    }
                }return true;
            }});
```

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue on the emulator or on an actual phone ? because the emulator is quite slow so it could explain why you have to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are [not moving `View`s the way they are supposed to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html), in Android?

`setPadding()` is not the best way to go about it.

---

Here [is an alternative way of Drag and Drop](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) for `View`s