# Drag and Drop component on ImageView

Tags: android, dynamically-generated

Can any one help me to know how to add `TextField` on `ImageView` Dynamically. And drag them to any position on that `ImageView` as we want...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relative layout as container of your imageView (or directly set your image as relativeLayout background) like in this manner:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<RelativeLayout>
```

and programatically, you get your imageView and add the textView to that:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (relativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
ImageView iv_myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
// Create new textView
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
// Here set style on textView
// Finally add textView to imageView
relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

About drag and drop there's plenty topics about.. see 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/try-androids-useful-drag-and-drop-api/

[drag and drop textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355798/drag-and-drop-textview)

Comment: Yeah, i was forgetful. i mean add it to the relativeLayout!